# R: Use loop with Conditions to join tables

Tags: r, loops, data.table, tidyverse

I currently have a file with 156 columns and 60 corresponding lookup tables, i.e. not all columns need a lookup table. I have written the joins all in one function, which also works well.

For some analysis I always go back to the file (without lookups) and read only the columns I need. Unfortunately, this then causes my function to stop working because of the missing columns.

My idea is to use a loop to compare the column names of the DT table with the elements of the lookup table list. If the name of the column matches the name in the list, then the join should be performed.

I work a lot with Tidyverse and am currently expanding my knowledge of data.table, so I have tried both packages.

Here is my approach using mtcars as an example. First with Tidyverse:

```
# dataframe
df <- mtcars

# lookuptables
cyl <- data.frame(id = c(4, 6, 8),
                  value = c("4-cyl", "6-cyl", "8-cyl"))

gear <- data.frame(id = c(3, 4, 5),
                   value = c("3-forward", "4-forward", "5-forward"))


# list and name elements
lkp <- list(cyl, gear)
names(lkp) <- c("cyl", "gear")



for(i in names(df)) {
        if(isTRUE(i %in% names(lkp))) {
                df_new <- left_join(df, lkp[[set_names(i)]], by = set_names("id", i)) %>% 
                        select(-c(set_names(i))) %>% 
                        rename(!!i := value)
        }
}

df_new
```

Unfortunately not all columns are changed via the join, but always only the last column that is found. The column cyl is like before.

```
 mpg    cyl disp  hp  drat wt    qsec   vs am  carb gear
 21.0   6   160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1   4    4-forward
 21.0   6   160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1   4    4-forward
 22.8   4   108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1   1    4-forward
 21.4   6   258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0   1    3-forward
 18.7   8   360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0   2    3-forward
```

My desired result would be the following:

```
 mpg    cyl   disp  hp  drat wt    qsec   vs am   carb gear
 21.0   6-cyl 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4-forward
 21.0   6-cyl 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4-forward
```

Here is my approach with data.table:

```
# datatable
dt <- mtcars
setDT(dt)


# lookuptables
cyl <- data.table(id = c(4, 6, 8),
                  value = c("4-cyl", "6-cyl", "8-cyl"))

gear <- data.table(id = c(3, 4, 5),
                   value = c("3-forward", "4-forward", "5-forward"))


# list and name elements
lkp <- list(cyl, gear)
names(lkp) <- c("cyl", "gear")


# for loop
for (i in names(dt)) {
        if(isTRUE(i %in% names(lkp))) {
                setkey(dt, setNames(i))
        }
}
```

If I want to use data.table, then I already get an error at setkey that the columns are not present:

```
Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) : 
  some columns are not in the data.table: setNames(i)
```

At the moment I can't understand why only the last column is changed in each case and I can't find my thinking error in the loop.

For data.table my knowledge is not very good yet. I assume that I can not use setkey in that way. Would I have to write out the full join here then if necessary?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: for `dplyr` the result is stored in `df_new` and the loop uses `df` as input : you should store the result in `df` so that all loop iterations are taken into account.

Comment: What @Waldi says.  Also, `for` loops use lazy evaluation, which may be an issue.  Better to use `lapply` (or similar), which forces evaluation.  You can get more information on lazy evaluation [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#lazy-evaluation).

Comment: @Waldi thanks!!!! Such a stupid mistake ....

Comment: @Limey: thank you for the hint. I have to admit, I need a bit time to understand it :-) I will try to use lapply! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### data.table approach:

```
for(col in intersect(names(dt),names(lkp))) {
  setnames(lkp[[col]], new=c(col,"value"))
  set(dt,j=col,value = dt[lkp[[col]], on=col]$value)
}
```

Note that if your lookup table columns were originally assigned as "cyl" ("gear") and "value", rather than "id" and "value", you could skip the setnames call in that loop, and you would have the even simpler:

```
for(col in intersect(names(dt),names(lkp))) set(dt,j=col,value = dt[lkp[[col]], on=col]$value)
```

Finally, if you neither want to change the colnames of your original look up tables, nor want to use the setnames approach you can do this:

```
for(col in intersect(names(dt),names(lkp))) {
  set(dt,j=col,value = dt[lkp[[col]], on = structure(c("id"),.Names=col)]$value)
}
```

In all cases, the output is:

```
head(dt)
    mpg   cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am      gear carb
1: 21.0 4-cyl  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1 3-forward    4
2: 21.0 4-cyl  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1 3-forward    4
3: 22.8 4-cyl  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1 3-forward    1
4: 21.4 4-cyl  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0 3-forward    1
5: 18.7 4-cyl  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0 3-forward    2
6: 18.1 4-cyl  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0 3-forward    1
```